# MySql Issue: Auto Incremented ID's are not working properly, ID's are getting misplaced

Tags: mysql

I have created one DB in Mysql;It is uploaded on server. But today i noticed one strange thing, that ID's from the same table are getting lost. I have set Auto_Increment for ID. So it will only Increment the ID's but now I can see that some of the records are being lost. In the place of that some other ID is there. For example: Order ID 1 should be in the first place but today some other ID lets call Order 5 was in place of ID 1. Well we can sort ID's anytime. But i didn't find Order ID 1 and Some other ID's like that anywhere.
I need help. What is wrong? any help will be fine.

Comment: This is not a sequence gap  issue. Complete Id data is lost. What do i do?

Comment: How's your insert SQL?

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO home_data (rdate,rzip,rstore,rname,remail,rphone,rcontacttwo,rstate,rcity,rlandmark,raddress,rcard,rpaytm,rmobi,rtotal) values ('$date','$zip','$store','$name','$email','$contact', '$contact2','$state','$city','$landmark','$address','$amount','$cash','$card','$paytm','$mobikwik', '$total')";

Comment: I am using mysqli_real_escape_string()

Comment: Can u give us the create table sql?

Comment: Are you certain that ID = 1 ever existed or did mysql allocate ID 1 and then throw the content away because it failed validation?

Answer (score 0):

You lost all the data of row or only lost the order of the ID field?

Example:

[image]

If only  the order, in case of using Auto_Increment, any record that had removed (or delete), it's order will not auto create again. Are you only insert data from the table, or have some delete query too ?

Comment: See complete order is getting lost. I am not using any delete or update command anywhere in my code

Comment: I have some projects use mysql, but I never had the same problem, I think I not the problem of mysql or Auto_Increment, try to determine common characteristics of the lost data rows. Echo the $sql and copy it the some database development tools to run and see the result. That the way I usually find out the problems with mysql.